# clang-format formats documentation comment

Tags: comments, clang-format

How can I tell clang-format to ignore documentation comments as follows

```
/***************************************************************************//**
  * @brief
  *   ...
*******************************************************************************/
void function(){
    ...
}
```

without limiting general comment formatting. Or manually turning clang-format off and on.

I tried

```
ReflowComments: false
PenaltyBreakComment: 1000000000
```

but this affects general comment formatting.